# IE Text shadows

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css

I'm a little confused about IE text shadows. As I can see Internet Explorer 11 supports it, and I have used it on a couple of sites where it has worked, but on other websites it stubbornly does not show up when I use the same exact format:

{text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000000;}

I have checked and re-checked all CSS stylesheets to make sure nothing is overriding it. I also tried using the filter for IE text shadow, but that did not work either.

So, my question is - if text-shadow works on some websites, why doesn't it work on others? Is there something else that may be interfering? FYI I'm using Joomla for all sites.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check it in the DOM inspector? IE11 has this feature (F12). If the `text-shadow` was overriden you'd see it immediately as a crossed-over property

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's being overwritten?  Use your developer tools to inspect the CSS applied to the element.

Comment: Yes sirs, I did check with developer tools. It is not crossed out. However, there is no checkbox with a checkmark next to it, unlike other CSS properties.

Comment: I see in developer tools on other sites that CSS gets converted to something like-->>> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(color=#000000, offX=1, offY=1);               BUT...even using that filter directly does not work on these other sites.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site, that causes problems? http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow - Text-shadow is supported in IE10 and IE11.

Comment: Right now, it's this one on an IP address: http://98.131.56.135/ , but I also had the same issue on other sites that are already live...so I'm assuming being on an IP address has nothing to do with it.

Comment: No, it's not related to the IP adresse. A domain name also just resolves to an IP address, so it's the same thing. I've found the problem, which is related to your meta setting - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

It tells Internet Explorer to emulate IE9, which doesnt support text-shadow (http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow).

Or set it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've seen that one.